# Most interesting industrial or environmental sound design (you've come across)?

Tags: sound-design

What kind of machines, devices, environments and other projects have you come across that you consider to be particularly interesting in terms of how humans (spontaneously?) shape their environment to sound in a particular way? We might exclude stuff like mobile phones, computers and electronic entertainment devices, because they tend to be quite common, unless there's something particularly interesting someone wants to point out.

What makes this particular example cool/interesting?

What do you think is the (general) purpose (if it's not self-evident) of the sound in this particular case? Or how do you perceive it?

Would also be interesting to make some distinction between commercial and non-commercial, because they tend to have slightly different goals.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have a long way to go, but here are some low tech solutions.

One simple example of how the sound of an environment is enhanced is ofcourse a sound barrier near a highway. It blocks/reflects/disperses the sounds created by the cars. 
A more sophisticated example is the usage of big trees (like populus*) next to noisy places. In the Netherlands we have seen a lot of this type of architectural enhancements since the 80s/90s. 
Still there are more developments being made, research from acousticians is also used to create less reverberant places (or better said, better controlled reverb).

*The populus is a very noisy tree and it masks the sound of engines/tires/airplanes very well. Other examples of masking are fountains (a new hype here in amsterdam, playground for kids, less noise experienced by residents.

Comment: Yeah, I too think that esp. the use of "designed" environmental sound might just be what may be coming, but not quite there yet. Like if we'd have more of things like Eno's "Music for Airports" -experiment. And took that kind of idea to e.g. mask traffic noise or make noisy machines sound different etc. More like tuning the noise, rather than damping it, or using totally "designed sound" for changing what something sounds like.

Answer (score 0):

I understand now :D

Giving electric cars the sound of gasoline motors to prevent accidents (electric cars are very quiet and so confusing for people crossing the road etc.)

Comment: What's confusing about the question?

Comment: That spontaneously irritated me a bit.

Comment: Well, it's spontaneous if e.g. a person has "a calling" to design sound for/of things and does it for some reason? ;) Otherwise one would not do it? From all the possible things one could do in the world and the reasons one could seek, one chooses to do something. So I call that "spontaneous" (although I don't mean spontaneous in the sense of something being "instant" or effortless). Why do we make movies, if historical humans (prior to movies) did not make movies, nor does any other species make movies to our knowledge? But we still do it, so again, it's some how...

Comment: ...spontaneous for an individual to do something for something to have a meaning (a meaning, which they have defined themselves).

Comment: The question is about identifying sound design projects that have modified the sound of our built/engineered environment or some engineered object from some previous or natural state. I.e. an environment or an engineered object becomes sonically "designed" somehow, rather than sounding what it would sound in its natural/"non-designed" state. I.e. environmental or industrial sound design. The modification of the sound of car doors to be more pleasant is one (but not very interesting) example.

Comment: Okay I see. So you basically wanna know the motivation and purpose of designing sound. And some examples.

Comment: no, I want to hear examples of environmental and industrial sound design that's particularly interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I really like Diego Stocco and how he explores the world around him in order to compose his pieces. His works amplify exactly what has always been there- that we are surrounded by interesting wonderful sounds that when mic'ed, change in timbre and pitch which expose the diversity/complexity of these sounds. Using lapel mics and contact mics on trees, cups of coffee, percolators etc.

Comment: Great, it's not industrial or environmental sound design though. But sampling and organic music making.